# Trouble setting Classpath for Cpsuite with Maven

Tags: maven, junit, classpathsuite

Using Maven I am creating a `jar-with-dependencies` for a project that uses [ClasspathSuite](https://github.com/takari/takari-cpsuite) to create a JUnit test suite. When running the jar from the command line I am running into an issue where the project classpath isn't being supplied like it would be in Eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/<dir>/BaseCategoryRunner
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.<dir>.BaseCat
egoryRunner
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 13 more
```

I need the project classpath so that ClasspathSuite can scan my files to build a junit class suite. I have been searching a number of ways to allow maven to include the classpath in my pom such as `<additionalClasspathElements>` or  `<Class-Path>` but I cannot get the value to appear in the system property `java.class.path`. At this point I am unsure if I am just walking down a rabbit hole that isn't going to work.

1. Is it possible to have a classpath in my jar's manifest that will point to one of the jar's directory? In this case ./com/....
2. How can I have this classpath referenced so that maven will include it when the jar is executed?